# Where can I share a Print and Play game?

Tags: print-and-play

I've been working on a hobby card game project for a while and I'm currently sharing it as a free Print & Play with a later option to support the project with buying the printed version.

Currently I had some success posting it on [r/boardgames](https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/gml5zd/card_game_about_programmersit_free_print_play_it/) and got a very positive response from the Reddit community. In this reddit thread someone suggested pnpparadise as another place to share Print & Play games.

Could you suggest me some other places, to share a free Print & Play version of a game?
It's a great way to collect a ton o of feedback as an indie game designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if website recommendations are off topic same way game recommendations are but will see!

https://playtest-coop.com is a site specifically for play testing print and play games. I've tried a few things from there

Since the global lockdown began however online play testing groups are more prevalent.  I've done more play testing of my own design in the last few months than I have in the last year.  You can find a list here https://cardboardedison.com/playtest-groups

The 'Remote Playtesting Group' on Saturday seems to the busiest with about 40 designers/testers meeting on the Discord server.

The Cardboard Edison website is a very good resource for games design/play testing advice and lists play testing groups around the world for when lockdown is over.   There is an absolute ton of other play testing resources online as well.

Just remember the golden rule, if 4 people spend 1 hour playing your game you owe the play testing world 4 hours back testing their games!

Comment: Thank for your time StartPlayer. Will check them out!

Answer (score 1):

Try the forums at Boardgamegeek https://boardgamegeek.com/forums/region/1/bgg (in thematicaly as well as regional appropriate subforum) and  another good possibility to show your game might be bringing it with you to a local boardgame meeting, hobby convention etc, maybe even a sponsored play at the local tabletop store (but ask the shopkeeper beforehand).